# Minor flaws in the new profile design

Tags: bug, design, profile-page

There are two minor issues with the profile layout/design. First, when mousing over the impact number, the box is clipped at the top by the top layout:

[image: clipped box]

Second, most of the explanation text boxes are that black background shown above, except for the post edits, helpful flags, and votes cast boxes -- those have an older-style white background:

[image: color choice]

Poking around in the CSS, it looks like anything displayed with the `title` property has the white backgrounds, which also includes the `badge{1,2,3}-alternate` classes.

Comment: I can reproduce the clipped box, but not the white background on the tooltips. Running chrome over ubuntu.

Comment: Firefox in both Linux (OpenSuSE) and WIndows 8.1 show the white background on tooltips that use the `title` property and not the `data-title` property (or maybe more likely, for CSS classes without the `css-tooltip` class).

Comment: I can confirm the colors on Win7 and on Linux Mint 17.2, clip exits on both as well.

Comment: I just checked with Firefox and I get the same - clip, but black tooltips. That's Firefox 43.0.4 and Chrome 47.0.2526.106 over Ubuntu 14.04 since I seem to be the odd one out.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty Black tooltips on everything? If you hover over the post edits, helpful flags, votes cast or the boxes with the numbers of each gold/silver/bronze badge? I just want to make sure we're looking at the same thing. I have FF 43.0.4 on Windows and 42.0 on Linux. Maybe it has to do with your window manager settings -- do you have a dark theme enabled or something?

Comment: For instance, if you hover over the "close" link under my question -- is that a white or black tooltip? Mine is white everywhere.

Comment: Yeah, they're all black. It could well be a system default; I'm running Unity with the default Ambiance theme, and there's definitely a lot of black-background tooltips around now that you mention it.

Comment: The former has been fixed....